# How to create netcdf file from excel sheet contain one variable values with corresponding lat long?

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am trying to create a nc file from excel file containing values in three column (lat, long and Precipitation). The data is gridded value of 0.05 degree resolution. The total number of grids is 1694. The data extent is 57 columns and 52 rows. I am not getting how to load the precipitation variable?.

I tried like this.

```
from netCDF4 import *
from numpy import *
from openpyxl import *
import time

#Load the data sheet
wb = load_workbook('D:\\R_Workspace\\UB_Try.xlsx')
ws = wb['UB_details']

#To get the prec variable
ppt = []
for i in range(2,1696):
   ppt.append(ws.cell(row=i,column=3).value)
ppt_arr = asarray(ppt)

#Writing nc file
nc_file = Dataset('D:\\R_Workspace\\Test.nc','w',format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')
nc_file.description = 'Example dataset'
nc_file.history = 'Created on ' +time.ctime(time.time())

#Defining dimensions
lon = nc_file.createDimension('lon',57)
lat = nc_file.createDimension('lat',52)

#Creating variables
latitude = nc_file.createVariable('Latitude',float32,('lat',))
latitude.units = 'Degree_North'
longitude = nc_file.createVariable('Longitude',float32,('lon',))
longitude.units = 'degree_East'
prec = nc_file.createVariable('prec',float32,('lon','lat'),fill_value = -9999.0)
prec.units = 'mm'

#Writing data to variables
lats = arange(16.875,19.425,0.05)
lat_reverse = lats[::-1]
lons = arange(73.325,76.175,0.05)
latitude[:] = lat_reverse
longitude[:] = lons
prec[:] = ppt_arr
nc_file.close()
```

I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\R_Workspace\Try.py", line 45, in <module>
    prec[:] = ppt_arr
  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 4358, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__setitem__
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1694 into shape (57,52)
```

Comment: Please specify *It is not working*. Show the traceback, if any, or the wrong output etc., i.e. provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you @MikeMüller I have mentioned the trackback in my query. actually my excel sheet has three column and 1964 rows excluding header.

Comment: *The total number of grids is 1694. The data extent is 57 columns and 52 rows.* But: `57 * 52 = 2964`

Comment: Yes @MikeMüller. actually it is a spatial dataand only 1694 grids has a value. remaining no data

Comment: @MikeMüller I just replace with your line but sir that is writing all zero value

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
prec[:] = ppt_arr
```

with:

```
temp = np.zeros(52 * 57, dtype=np.float32)
temp[:ppt_arr.size] = ppt_arr
prec[:] = temp
```

This creates a temporary array of zeros and fills the number of valid element with your values for `pt_arr` before assigning to the netCDF array.

Comment: Are you sure you also added line `temp[:ppt_arr.size] = ppt_arr`?

Comment: Did you check the content of `ppt_arr`?

Comment: it is writing values but when I plot the out put is wrong. actually the spatial resolution of grids 0.05 degree. It is showing 1. my coordinate increment is 0.05

Comment: Maybe it is due to the `np.float32`. See my updated answer.

Comment: still no sir.. I feel problem with spatial reference. here I am referring coordinates so how to give that? any idea pls

Comment: Are the `1`s actually  in the netCDF file or only in the plot? Check with `ncdump`.

Comment: it is writing values but coordinates are not in proper. If I plot extent are Top-52.5, left-0.5, right 57.5, bottom-0.5. But actual coordinates are(T-19.425, L-73.325, R-76.175, b-16.875.

Comment: sir also ncdump: nc open failed